# Сторонние шрифты в css

Tags: css, шрифты

Ремарка - новичок. Вопрос странный и возможно глупый но я реально не могу понять. Допустим я принялся верстать макет заказчика. Дохожу к примеру до какого нибудь блока текста и вижу что у него какой то специфический шрифт. Иду гуглить этот шрифт - оказывается шрифт платный. Возникает вопрос: должен ли я покупать его или же заказчик должен предоставить что то типа ключа? В теме шритов и их подключения вообще ноль.

Answer (score 0):

Большинство шрифтов платные. Особенно те что идут с пакетом Adobe. Если вас совесть мучать не будет, то сможете найдите "бесплатную" версию или скачайте бесплатный [аналог](https://fonts.google.com/) Если же ваш заказчик - это серьезная Европейская компания и ваш проект >20к$ лучше купить право использования. (Что б снять возможные юридические иски). Но обычно ни кто по поводу шрифтов заказчика не беспокоит, и обычно в смете это идет под пунктом - Другие расходы